# How to remove a row from the Table on an action performed

Tags: jquery

I am create a table with the response object recievied from server .

In case the checkbox is unchecked , how can i remove the remove that particular row from the table ??

This is my code

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vxe2d2hh/10/

could you please let em know how to do this .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `this.checked` to determine the checked state for current checkbox. If it is false, traverse to closest tr using `.closest("tr")` along with `.remove()` to remove it:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
 var $this = $(this);
 if(!this.checked)
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6m75vawk/)**

Comment: Thanks  , could you please see this fiddle , http://jsfiddle.net/vxe2d2hh/11/   in case if clicked on checkbox and  if cancel is clicked on confirm box , how can i keep the checkbox checked .

Comment: i used $(this).prop( "checked", true ); in else part  is that also is fine ??